How can i remap a point in R2 from a set of 4 arbitrary points into a range (0, 0) - (1, 1)?
Consider a closed space in R2 that has x and y range from 0 to 1. Lets call it S1
Inside this space, lays 4 arbitrary points named A, B, C and D, which form a quadrilateral. This area can be called S2
Considering that the line AD forms a local x axis inside S2 and the y axis is defined by AB, being A the origin of the space S2:
S2 enclosed in S1 by 4 control points, A, B, C and D
Note that AD and AB defining the x and y axes are not enough do define the space S2, C is a point that also needs to be considered, as when C is plotted into the function, it should return the point (1, 1)
Now, i can map a point from S2 into S1 using simple linear interpolation like the following:
P' = lerp(lerp(A, D, Px), lerp(B, C, Px), Py)
But i want to do the opposite operation, i want to convert a point that is in S1 and calculate the local position if it were in S2
My first attempt was to decompose the lerp function into lerp(a, b, k) = a + (b-a)k and calculate the inverse function, however things got out of hand pretty quickly, considering that the original function not only have nested lerps, but treats the original points components individually.
Is there an easier way to calculate the inverse of this function?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This is called inversion of q1-interpolation
Suppose you have $4$ points $(x_i,y_i)$ for $i=1..4$ and a point $(x,y)$ inside this quadrilateral.
And you are searching $X,Y$ the reverse interpolated in the unit square.

The direct transformation $(X,Y)\mapsto(x,y)$ is as below

$p_1=(1-X)(1-Y)\\
p_2=X(1-Y)\\
p_3=XY\\
p_4=Y(1-X)$
$x=p_1x_1+p_2x_2+p_3x_3+p_4x_4\\
y=p_1y_1+p_2y_2+p_3y_3+p_4y_4$

The reverse one $(x,y)\mapsto(X,Y)$ is a bit more involved

$a=x_1\\
b=x_2-x_1\\
c=x_4-x_1\\
d=x_1-x_2+x_3-x_4$
$\alpha=y_1\\
\beta =y_2-y_1\\
\gamma=y_4-y_1\\
\delta=y_1-y_2+y_3-y_4$
$u=c\beta-b\gamma\\
v=c\delta-d\gamma\\
w=b\delta-d\beta$
$X_0=b(y-\alpha)-\beta(x-a)\\
Y_0=c(y-\alpha)-\gamma(x-a)$
You now have to solve the quadratic $At^2+Bt+C=0$
$A=vw\\
B=uu-wY_0-vX_0\\
C=X_0Y_0$
$\Delta=\sqrt{B^2-4AC}$
if $A\neq 0$ then $\begin{cases}t_1=\frac{-B+\Delta}{2A}\\
t_2=\frac{-B-\Delta}{2A}\end{cases}$ and choose the one which belongs to $[0,1]$, we call it $t$.
else if $A=0,B\neq 0$ then $t=-\frac CB$ else $t=0$
Finally you get

$X=\frac 1u(Y_0-vt)\\Y=\frac 1u(wt-X_0)$

Note 1: normally if your quadrilateral is not degenerated then $u\neq 0$
Note 2: these steps are copied from old work of mine (C code), initially I solved it by inverting the matrix derived from the direct calculation, you can try to solve by yourself if you want to and/or read literature about finite elements linear q1-interpolation.

Thank you! It worked perfectly!
